# constrained regression with many variables

Tags: matrix, constraints, stata

I have around 200 dummies, and wish to run a constrained OLS regression where I impose that the sum of all coefficients on the dummies is equal to 1.

One option is to type:

```
constraint define 1 dummy_1+dummy_2 +...+dummy_200=1

cnsreg y x_1 x_2 dummy_1-dummy_200, c(1)
```

...but typing the constraint out would obviously be very painful.

Is there a way to quickly define such a large constraint? The matrix form would be very quick and straightforward, but after much reading online and in Stata guide, it is not clear to me how to do constraints in matrix form, and if they are even possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two sides to this, how to do it and whether it will work in any statistical sense.

How to do it seems easier than you fear as the difficult bit is just inserting "+" signs between the variable names, and that's string manipulation. Something like

```
unab myvars : dummy_* 
local myvars : subinstr local myvars " " "+", all
mac li 
constraint 1 `myvars' = 1
```

should get you started. The `macro list` is so you can see what you did, especially if it is not what you want.

Whether it will work for you statistically is outside the scope of this forum, but if that's the only constraint note that it's consistent with all kinds of negative and positive coefficients. Perhaps there are special features of your problem that make it a natural constraint, but my intuition is that such a model will be hard to estimate.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a completely different approach. Such constraints typically occur when trying out a different coding scheme for a set of indicator variables. If that is the case then I would use Stata's [factor variables](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?fvvarlist), combined with [margins with the contrast operators](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?margins_contrast).